# Entity Framework related entity, wrong loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm facing a problem with EF's related entities.

I have the following code:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

When i get a Customer entity the Status attr is lazy loaded, so far so good. However, the status obj is wrong.

For Example. I have a customer related with status id 5; But when I got it the status id is 1.

The entities above are just examples. In the real ones, all the related fields behave the same.

Any help will be great.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have the data properly saved to database tables ?

Comment: Yeah, everything is ok on db..... thanks

Comment: With this model you even won't be able to run any query or perform lazy loading because it will throw model validation exceptions. Can you try to show an example model that is closer to your real entities? What is the customer id related to status id 5? 1 or 5?

Comment: The model schema is the same, I just removed the other attributes to make it simpler.

I have 5 Status records. Ids 1 to 5.

I have 1 Candidato Record related to Status 5. But when I got this, it comes with Status id 1.

Did I Made myself clearer? Thanks

Comment: No, it's not clearer. Making the question "simpler" is a good idea but you made it so simple that the problem is invisible now. As said, the model in your question is invalid and it will throw exceptions before you even can query anything.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED

It was my mistake.

I changed to this and it worked.

Thanks for help.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StatusId")]
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```